Sleep Paralysis in Torah?
My friend recently mentioned to me that he has sleep paralysis and I was wondering what the Torah has to say about it:

Why does it happen according to the Torah?
How does one stop it from happening again according to the Torah?
Does it affect someone spiritually speaking?

Please provide sources that directly/indirectly speak about/or describe sleep paralysis.
